# Swift: How to save data to var in Model form segue?

Tags: swift, uikit, delegates, segue

I have:
Model with Class GameBrain, ViewController that opens in segue TableViewController.

In TableViewController I need to edit var that is in GameBrain to 0.
When I change its value there using gameBrain.myVar = 0 and print its value from TableViewController its 0 as expected, but when I go back to ViewController its unchanged.

I tried to change its value using delegate (code below), but it doesnt even print "IT WORKS!" just so I know its going the right direction.

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't function resetPlayerScore() called?

TableViewController:

```
protocol MenuTableViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func resetPlayerScore()
}

class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    weak var delegate: MenuTableViewControllerDelegate?
    private let gameBrain = GameBrain()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            delegate?.resetPlayerScore()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
extension GameBrain: MenuTableViewControllerDelegate {
    func resetPlayerScore() {
        print("IT WORKS!")
    }
```

Comment: Add the code for the ViewController which opens the table view to see how you configure the tableViewController before you open it. Plus in didSelectRowAt inside the switch you need to call resetPlayerScore() from the delegate like this delegate?.resetPlayerScore(). this will print print("IT WORKS!") it the delegate not nil

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I truly appreciate your help.
TableViewController is created and performed by segue made in storyboards, so I didn't configure it at all. 

I tried the delegate?.resetPlayerScore() correctly, I just forgot to put it in there while creating this shorter version of the code for putting it here :) Bud even with this delegate?. ... call it doesnt work

Comment: I think the problem is this " weak var delegate: MenuTableViewControllerDelegate?" write this instead.   var delegate: MenuTableViewControllerDelegate! , and make sure you assign the target receiver delegate.

Comment: @san_sun it should be weak var. to avoid retain cycle because viewController hold a reference to the table view which is the segue and the table view hold reference  for viewController  which is the delegate

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an example for you. viewController should implement the delegate not the GameBrain Model

check the code below i hope that what you are looking for

```
protocol MenuTableViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
func resetPlayerScore(gameBrain: GameBrain)
}

class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {


weak var delegate: MenuTableViewControllerDelegate?
private var gameBrain = GameBrain()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    return cell
}

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
      gameBrain.value += 1
    
      switch indexPath.row {
      case 0:
          delegate?.resetPlayerScore(gameBrain: gameBrain)
          dismiss(animated: true)
      default:
          break
      }
  }
}

class GameBrain {
    var value: Int = 0
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

  private var gameBrain = GameBrain()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if let destination = segue.destination as? MenuTableViewController {
          destination.delegate = self
      }
  }


}


extension ViewController: MenuTableViewControllerDelegate {
    func resetPlayerScore(gameBrain: GameBrain) {
        self.gameBrain = gameBrain
        print(gameBrain.value)
    }
}
```

i created viewController and MenuTableViewController in the storyboard and the segue in the storyboard as well you have to set the delegate = viewController before navigating to the tableViewController and you can do that in this function [prepare(for:sender:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare)

Comment: I am sorry for answerting this late. I wrote the answer but didn't send it :D 
It works now! Thank you very much, Sir!